# Fill masked array values with reflect padding in python efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science

I have a square matrix (image) with masked values in an area. The mask corresponds to missing values in areas close to the border (always). I want to create a new image where the masked values are replaced with the reflect padding of the values where actual image values exist. How can I do so in python?

In the example below I want to replace (left panel) the yellow area with the reflected image of the middle panel, where data exist. The result should be something like the right panel image (the  padding here  is not the appropriate reflect padding I am after, as I just used the naive recipe  `right_image = np.where(temp.mask,middle_image[::-1,::-1],middle_image)`)

[image]

**edit**: I tried to transverse the image row by row, and use numpy reflect padding, with the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
# Row Reflect 
# Here out_image is the original image, where -2 is no data value
xx = []
for i in range(6000): # Number of rows
    temp1 = np.ma.array(out_image[0,i,:],mask= out_image[0,i,:]==-2) # Create mask per row, -2 is the masked value
    edges = ma.flatnotmasked_edges(temp1) # Find edges
    #if edges is not None:
    xx += [np.expand_dims(np.pad(temp1.data[edges[0]:edges[1]],((edges[0],temp1.shape[0]-edges[1])),mode='reflect'),0)]
out = np.concatenate(xx)
#out = out.reshape(2000,2000)
```

The result is incorrect. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to add a reflection (180° rotation) to a masked area. You can use `scipy.ndimage.rotate` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html)) and add both images.

Does something like this work?:

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
# sample mask for a 768 * 1024 image
line = lambda x: 400 - 200 * x/800   
mask = np.indices(im.shape[:2])
mask = line(mask[0])<mask[1]

plt.imshow(im*mask[:,:,None])
plt.show()

im2=rotate(im, 180) 
plt.imshow(im*mask[:,:,None] + im2*~mask[:,:,None])
plt.show()
```

[image: Original Image] [image: Output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, no, a reflection is not equivalent with a 180 rotation. The point-need here is that a reflection on the missing part is a smooth transition from the left to the right and can be used as data augmentation - for my needs - in deep learning training problem I have.